# how do I continue my code so that the circle (player) doesn't go through the rectangle?

Tags: javascript

There is a collision, I find it on the side of the rectangle (I can’t do it otherwise), but I don’t know how to stop the circle, that is, so that I can’t go any further (and at the same time not get stuck and can go back)

```
class Rect
{
    constructor(x,y,w,h)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
    drawRect()
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 100, 20);
    }
    checkcollision(player)
    {
        let distX = Math.abs(player.cx - this.x - this.w / 2);
        let distY = Math.abs(player.cy - this.y - this.h / 2);
        if (distX > this.w / 2 + player.radius || distY > this.h / 2 + player.radius) {
            
            
          } else {
            
           
          }
  
        
        
}

}
```

move code

````
chekcollision()
      {
        if(this.cx - this.radius < 0)
        {
            this.cx = this.radius;
        }
        if(this.cx + this.radius > 600)
        {
            this.cx = 600 - this.radius;
        }
        if(this.cy - this.radius < 0)
        {
            this.cy = this.radius;
        }
        if(this.cy + this.radius > 400)
        {
            this.cy = 400 - this.radius;
        }
      }
```
````

Comment: Have you checked out questions in the [tag:collision-resolution] tag for some ideas? We have lots of prior answers about this topic. Note that users here won't be able to tell you much about how to stop your player's movement if you haven't shown the code you use to move the player. What you've labeled "move code" seems to actually be checking the player against the bounds of the screen/play area.

Comment: Perhaps just apply a force in the opposite direction with the players speed when the player is inside the collider? That could also fix problems, as just stopping the movement may end up with side effects like getting stuck inside colliders rather than being pushed out as i mentioned.